# grep utility and redirect and append standard output

Tags: linux

I need to create a single command that uses the grep utility to search for the acronym EOF in all files within the current working directory. This command should redirect and append standard output to a file called results.txt and the error output to a file called error.txt

I am having trouble testing these scenarios. This is what I have can someone please help me with this.

```
grep -r 'EOF' | cat > results.txt 2>> error.txt
```

When I test this results.txt has EOF in it. If I throw a -p (my supposed error) after the cat it erases results.txt. I'm trying to test the error.txt. Am I just thinking of this the wrong way????

Answer (score 0):

`grep -r 'EOF' | cat > results.txt 2>> error.txt`

Problems first:
 • `-r` is the recursive flag — this will search all files in the current and in all subdirectories.
 • putting `results.txt` in the current directory *while* grepping the current directory — grep will find the results in results.txt that it already found in other files.
 • *"UUOC"* ... you don't want to pipe through `cat`

grep in current directory, putting results and errors somewhere else (here, put in the parent directory)
 `grep 'EOF' * >> ../results.txt 2> ../error.txt`
This will append to results.txt, but overwrite error.txt `>` is "on-to" overwriting a file, while `>>` is "append-to".

grep some other directory, putting results in current directory
`grep 'EOF' subdir/* >> results.txt 2> error.txt`

These two will spit out errors for any directories found in the search directory.

I prefer `find`:
`find ./subdir -type f -exec fgrep 'EOF' {} + >> results.txt 2> error.txt`
Finds only *files* `-type f` in or below the directory `./subdir` and fgrep ("fixed" grep, it's faster since there is no regex in "EOF") — fgrep all the files found, writing output and errors to the files as above.
Add the "depth" parameter to search only the given directory, not sub-directories:
`find ./subdir -depth 1 -type f -exec (...etc...)`